# How to set up shared `system.webServer` settings for all sites on an IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, machine.config

I'm setting up a new webserver in our hosting environment. It's a new VM that will only ever be used by us, so I can do what I want with it (within reason). It's running IIS 7 on Windows 2008 R2, with ASP.Net 4.0 installed on the system.

I'd quite like to force all sites on the server to use the following [`system.webServer`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver) settings, unless they are explicitly overridden, but adding them to the [`Machine.config` or `Web.config`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) files in the [Framework config folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms228112%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions) doesn't seem to have any effect.

The settings I'm trying to force are as follows. I know these settings work fine within an individual site's `Web.config` (because I've copy/pasted them from a production site I configured myself) and I know that [IIS URL Rewrite Module 2](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-url-rewrite-module-20) is definitely installed.

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".air"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".ttf"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".otf"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".air" mimeType="application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-truetype"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/x-font-opentype"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"/>
    </staticContent>
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server">
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+"/>
                <action type="Rewrite" value=""/>
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

These settings should mean that the `X-Powered-By:` HTTP header is absent and the `Server:` header is empty, but when I test this, I get the following:

```xml
[12:35:56] owen@plum:~$ curl -I http://new.server.ip
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 689
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 May 2013 15:11:24 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "2ce2122ec4fce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 14 May 2013 11:36:16 GMT
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is it just that the `system.webServer` section cannot be inherited from these default configuration files?

Comment: Try it in ALL_CAPS? ServerVariables are generally all in uppercase.

Comment: Nah, the excerpt isn't the problem, as I mentioned in the question, this is a config excerpt that I know works elsewhere. (And no, headers aren't ALL_CAPS in HTTP, just when we access them from ASP or ASP.Net.)

Answer (score 1):

See this question from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/363049/saving-website-level-rewrite-rules-to-applicationhost-config). It would appear you can specify IIS-wide rewrite rules from the applicationHost.config file in C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\config. This then allows management and inheritance of rules via IIS.

EDIT: OK, that doesn't work... try [what's recommended here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4541885/418297), see if that makes a difference (forcing all modules to run for all requests may force the rewriter to pick up the inherited rewrite settings correctly).

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference either, I'm afraid.

Comment: For the record, you also suggested I check the same file in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config`, but that also doesn't appear to resolve the problem.

Comment: There isn't a `<modules/>` section in the `applicationHost.config`; adding that attribute to the `<globalModules/>` node doesn't make any difference. (And, interestingly, every time I edit the `system32` `applicationHost.config`, the `SysWOW64` gets edited identically by IIS.)